# find and replace using sed command

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, sed

I want to find single quote `'` between double quotes and replace it with (back slash single quote single quote) `\' '` using sed command.

input = `'gender':"Men's",'colour':'Red','name':"Men's levi's"`

output = `'gender':"Men\' 's",'colour':'Red','name':"Men\' 's levi\' 's"`

I tried this where I can replace comma with pipe but when trying to replace single quote with `\' '` it doesn't work:

```
sed 's/(\"[^"\'']\{1,\}),([^"\'']\{1,\}\")/\1 | \2/g' test.csv
```

Comment: Would you mind showing your efforts?

Comment: @revo I tried this where i can replace comma with pipe but when trying to replace single quote with \' ' it doesn't work     sed 's/\(\"[^"\'']\{1,\}\),\([^"\'']\{1,\}\"\)/\1 | \2/g'  test.csv ...i am new to sed so i really don't have idea how to do it in proper way

Comment: I've answered your question and hope that helps. If I'm honest, your question header was a little vague, but I only say that to help with avoiding those dreaded 'down votes', if that's something that matters to you. Good luck with sed! There is another Stack community called Unix and Linux. Your question may have been more suited there?

Comment: Adding `awk` to tags is not a good idea as OP explicitly said `sed` every where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed` you could do this:

```
sed -e ":a"
    -e "s/'\([^\\\":]*\(\\.[^\\\":]*\)*\"\)/\\\\\f \f\1/"
    -e "ta"
    -e "s/\\\\\f \f/\\\' '/g" file
```

Linebreaks and indentations are for readability. The whole point is that you first match single quotes that are followed by a double quote (might not be immediately), replace it with a `\\\f \f` (`\\` a literal backslash, `\f` form feed) do the same thing using a loop (`t`) then you replace previous replacement with your desired string. The main regex also takes care from escaped double quotation marks inside a double quoted string but it fails if you have colons `:` or commas `,` within it.

One-liner:

```
sed -e ":a" -e "s/'\([^\\\":]*\(\\.[^\\\":]*\)*\"\)/\\\\\f \f\1/" -e "ta" -e "s/\\\\\f \f/\\\' '/g" file
```

Comment: Isn't economy a factor? Is not the shortest and most effective way, the way to a solution? In any answer?

Comment: @revo Thank you very much it helps me!

Comment: @johnny_moss I won't sacrifice precision for a shorter, imprecise solution. If answer doesn't cover true cases it doesn't matter whether it's short or not. Simply, it couldn't be an answer. I'm not sure what you meant by *Isn't economy a factor?* but talking performance-wise this doesn't overlook performance beside its precision.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do that using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
     if (split($i, a, / *: */) == 2 && a[2] ~ /^"/) {
        gsub("\047",  "\\\047 \047", a[2])
        $i=a[1] ":" a[2]
     }
} 1' file
```

```
'gender':"Men\' 's",'colour':'Red','name':"Men\' 's levi\' 's"
```

Comment: @johnny_moss It does not mean other related answers could not help!

Comment: @revo: absolutely. but the OP specified sed, and that was my point.  You could answer that question in a myriad of ways. I'm just trying to abide by the forums protocols; I appreciate their specificity.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks a lot  your solution is working although i was looking for sed command i appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @johnny_moss people ask  for all sorts of wacky things in their questions, it usually just means that's all they know, and it's not a reason to not suggest a potentially better approach.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT, all you need is:

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]+"' '{gsub(/\047/,"\\\047 \047",RT); ORS=RT} 1' file
'gender':"Men\' 's",'colour':'Red','name':"Men\' 's levi\' 's"
```